# How to format Filter Criteria on Lambda Functions that are triggered via Kinesis Streams for DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I have a dynamodb table that has a Kinesis stream attached to it. See the relevant cloudformation configuration here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-kinesisstreamspecification

Recently, AWS announced [Filtering Event Sources for AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/filtering-event-sources-for-aws-lambda-functions/)

My goal would be to filter all events that **begins with** a specific string.

For example - say the original table has a document like:

```
"dynamodb": {
            "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1640276115300,
            "Keys": {
                "pk": "foo:random",
                "sk": "bar:something"
            },
            .....
```

I want to filter all events that start with `bar:`. The data comes in this format in the lambda function logs:

```
{
"Records": [
    {
        "kinesis": {
            "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "partitionKey": "E7DF48140C98F2557BDAF0126B8443AC",
            "sequenceNumber": "49624912313474127477164618281231039365742153203189809218",
            "data": "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",
            "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1640276115.796
        },
        "eventSource": "aws:kinesis",
        "eventVersion": "1.0",
        "eventID": "shardId-000000000004:49624912313474127477164618281231039365742153203189809218",
        "eventName": "aws:kinesis:record",
        "invokeIdentityArn": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/acct-managed/foo-bar-role",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:111111111111:stream/foo-bar-stream-role/consumer/foo-bar-consumer:1638560626"
    }
]
}
```

Once `data` is decoded it looks like:

```
{
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "eventID": "a2ea9f4a-5e9f-4300-a4f2-9aecf7e36e04",
        "eventName": "MODIFY",
        "userIdentity": null,
        "recordFormat": "application/json",
        "tableName": "foo-bar",
        "dynamodb": {
            "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1640276115300,
            "Keys": {
                "pk": "foo:random",
                "sk": "bar:something"
            },
            "NewImage": {...},
            "OldImage": {...},
            "SizeBytes": 634
        },
        "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
    }
```

What I have tried so far:

```
        FilterCriteria:
          Filters: 
            - Pattern: "{\"data\": { \"sk\": [ { \"prefix\": \"bar:\"} ] }}"


          Filters:
            - Pattern: "{\"data\": { \"dynamodb\": { \"sk\": [ { \"prefix\": \"bar:\"} ] }} }"
```

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get it working using the following:

```yaml
FilterCriteria:
  Filters:
    - Pattern: "{\"data\": { \"dynamodb\": { \"NewImage\": { \"sk\": { \"S\": [{ \"prefix\": \"rims:\" }] }}}}}"
```